# Speed up Voxelization / Intersection Tests

Tags: python, optimization, bounding-box, triangulation, voxel

I am currently working on a STL voxelization based on sparse octree.
I have a file with around 100,000 triangles in the format--- [ [ Point1 x-coordinate , Point1y , Point1z ] , [P2x , P2y , P2z] , [P3x , P3y , P3z] ] for each triangle.

I have a working solution for the voxelization of the hull but it is very very slow (10 secs on my Computer).
It needs to be around 1 second. (Total solid voxelization with an 8 level deep octree should take around 2 seconds)

Right now I am parsing the octree for each triangle.
For the intersection check I need to calculate the oriented bounding box of each of the 100,000 triangles. Right before parsing the octree for each triangle.

Only calculating the bounding box for all of the 100,000 triangles already takes aorund 0.800 seconds. That's way to long.
I am working with "Standard" Python 3 in PyCharm. I think its CPython if I am not wrong.

```
for triangle in triangle_list:
    'this variables represent the x,y,z value of all three vertices of the triangle'
    'in tests this method was found to be superior to the 2D array way '

    P1x = triangle[0][0]
    P1y = triangle[0][1]
    P1z = triangle[0][2]
    P2x = triangle[1][0]
    P2y = triangle[1][1]
    P2z = triangle[1][2]
    P3x = triangle[2][0]
    P3y = triangle[2][1]
    P3z = triangle[2][2]

    'the bounding box for the triangle is determined'
    'i used python integrated min max methods to find the smalles x,y,z value for all of the three vertices'


    bbtrxmin = min(P1x, P2x, P3x)
    bbtrxmax = max(P1x, P2x, P3x)
    bbtrymin = min(P1y, P2y, P3y)
    bbtrymax = max(P1y, P2y, P3y)
    bbtrzmin = min(P1z, P2z, P3z)
    bbtrzmax = max(P1z, P2z, P3z)
```

Because I am completely new to programming I have no clue what I can change up, to speed up the process. I have already searched for another algorithm but it didnt change much.

Things I have tried:

Alternative A:

```
P1t=triangle[0]
P2t=triangle[1]
P3t=triangle[2]

bbtrxmin = min(P1t[0], P2t[0], P3t[0])
bbtrxmax = max(P1t[0], P2t[0], P3t[0])
bbtrymin = min(P1t[1], P2t[1], P3t[1])
bbtrymax = max(P1t[1], P2t[1], P3t[1])
bbtrzmin = min(P1t[2], P2t[2], P3t[2])
bbtrzmax = max(P1t[2], P2t[2], P3t[2])
```

Alternative B:

```
def maX(a , b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    else: 
        return b

def miN(a , b):
    if a < b:
        return a
    else:
        return b  

P1t=triangle[0]
P2t=triangle[1]
P3t=triangle[2]

bbtrxmin = miN(P1t[0], miN(P2t[0], P3t[0]))
bbtrxmax = maX(P1t[0], maX(P2t[0], P3t[0]))
bbtrymin = miN(P1t[1], miN(P2t[1], P3t[1]))
bbtrymax = maX(P1t[1], maX(P2t[1], P3t[1]))
bbtrzmin = miN(P1t[2], miN(P2t[2], P3t[2]))
bbtrzmax = maX(P1t[2], maX(P2t[2], P3t[2]))
```

Alternative A was slightly slower but there was no significant difference.
Alternative B was around 1 second (definition of functions not included).
Target for this operation should not be over 0.100 secs maximum.

Do you have any idea how to speed up the calculation of a simple 3D oriented bounding box for 100,000 triangles? I have to use Python but I can vary the compiler.

Do you have any suggestion how to speed up the whole STL / Octree Voxelization process? Maybe I dont even need to check all triangles? I ve read lots of papers and most of them checked every triangle, but if you have any good idea around that I am open to it.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT 17.09.2020:

I am using PyPy now because I hope that the JIT Comiler can amplify the speed dramatically.
I did a few tests and the results are great.
Everything is running way faster, but  the bottleneck is still the following bit of code:

```
bbtrxmax = max(P1x, P2x, P3x)
bbtrymin = min(P1y, P2y, P3y)
bbtrymax = max(P1y, P2y, P3y)
bbtrzmin = min(P1z, P2z, P3z)
bbtrzmax = max(P1z, P2z, P3z)
```

to determine the bounding box. The rest of the code (around hundred lines of code with different variables run in 300 ms and this bit takes over 4 secs for the 100,000 repetitions.

Any new suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you’re trying to do: do you need one bounding box per triangle or the overall bounding box for all triangles together? Seems like the first but just checking.

A couple of possible ways to attack this problem:

- Try with NumPy arrays, as min() and .max() operation can work on entire slices of arrays (1D vectors, 2D arrays, etc...)
- Numba, Cython and f2py can be good alternatives when raw speed is needed: for Cython you may want to mix Python and C (or write your loop in C directly). F2py wraps fortran modules and it looks it would be very easy to code in your case.

Comment: Sorry that I was not specfic enough. I need one bounding box per triangle, to go through the voxel octree and check if the bounding box and the voxel intersect.